# Does jQuery Mobile provide a mechanism to extend it's theming model

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a custom class to the jQuery Mobile theme. The CSS should look something like this:

```
.ui-icon-form-ok-f {
    background-color: #f09000 !important;
    data-icon: check !important;
}
```

but how can I get jQuery Mobile to recognize this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to recognize a custom icon style to jqm

---

### For each elements of any

When you set `[data-icon=AAA]` on buttons, jqm creates `<span class="ui-icon-AAA">` inside the buttons.

That is:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="form-ok-f">custom icon button</a>
```

When loads this html, jqm creates like this:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="form-ok-f" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c">
   <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">custom icon button</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-form-ok-f ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
   </span>
</a>
```

So, jqm can recognize your custom-icon-class.

```
.ui-icon-form-ok-f {
    background-color: #f09000 !important;
    background-position:-252px 50% !important; /* this mean 'data-icon="check"' on css */
}​​​​
```

#### By applying this way, pages can load "ui-icon-alt"

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="check ui-icon-alt">custom icon button</a>
```

Jqm renders Black icons (Alt icon color) instead of White icons.

---

### For each theme of any

If you want to 'customize' icon for each theme of any, you should be loaded js like this:

```
$(function(){
 var $alttheme = new Array( "f", "g" );　// this arr means 'data-theme="f", data-theme="g"' 
 var at = new Array();
 for( t in $alttheme ){
  at.push(':jqmData(theme="' + alttheme[t] + '"):jqmData(icon="check") > span > .ui-icon');
 }
 $(at.join()).addClass('ui-icon-"YOUR CUSTOM NAMES"');
});
```

*YOUR CUSTOM NAME  (eg.form-ok, form-ng ...)

OR

```
$(function(){
 $(':jqmData(theme="f"):jqmData(icon="check") > span > .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-form-ok-f');
 $(':jqmData(theme="g"):jqmData(icon="check") > span > .ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-form-ok-g');
});
```

The former adds the same class to icons in "theme g" and "theme f", the latter adds respectively a separate class to icons in "theme g" and "theme f".

---

### At last

i've to prepare for [some samples](http://jsfiddle.net/FQY9K/).

Comment: Thank you very, very much Maco. This is very well explained and a very helpful example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override also other classes, like `.ui-bar-f`, `.ui-body-f`, `.ui-btn-up-f`,... and then use the attribute `data-theme="f"` of each tag to specify that you want to use this new theme for the component, but I have not managed to test it.

More information is in [jQuery-Mobile docs about theming](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/themes.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to find the perfect solution, but your link to theming (especially the 'overriding themes' section), was a good starting point. For now I'm keeping different themes in different files depending on my project, but would still love to find a solution to creating my own jquery mobile theme.

Comment: Did you try [Theme Roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) for creating your own theme?

Comment: Yes, thank you kindly Pablo. Unfortunately my requirement is to 'extend' the theme, rather than to customize the existing theme. I was trying to see if there is a way to add new CSS class types in a way that the jQuery Mobile theming engine will support it. So that if I created .ui-icon-form-ok-f and .ui-icon-form-ok-g (which are my own classes), it would change the look if I told jQuery Mobile to use the f or the g theme. No worries though, I created separate CSS files to support my different themes ;-) I was just hoping to find a better way.